# c++11 use behavior of statically asserted template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a templated class where I ensure the type parameter is a subclass of some abstract base class like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
    static_assert(
        std::is_base_of<MyBase, T>::value, 
        "T must be a descendant of MyBase"
    );

    void SomeMethod() 
    {
        auto bar = T();
        //or
        auto bar = T("Constructor with parameter")
        bar.someFunctionOnMyBase();
    }
};
```

Now in programming languages like C# or Java I can use this information and use he type information to call methods on the template type. Is such thing possible? Bonus points if it also possible to call constructors with the correct parameters.

Comment: Yes  you can do `auto bar = T();` (assuming T is default constructible etc.). Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @M.M Part of it. What if T is not default constructible? Also how to call the method `someFunctionOnMyBase` method?

Comment: If `T` is not default constructible, then you have a more difficult problem on your hands. There is not likely to be a truly generic way to instantiate any `T` with the proper arguments (what would the value of those arguments be? Default? What about arguments with no default constructors? etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is totally fine (as long as both the constructor that you intend to call and the destructor of class `T` are publicly accessible).

As a matter of fact you don't even need to have the `static_assert`, and as long as a member function `T::someFunctionOfMyBase` exists (even if it isn't the one defined in `MyBase` and just happens to share the name), this will still compile.

Comment: I see that's awesome. Why would you ever define the static assert like in my example?

Comment: @JohnSmith When you have a lot of nested calls involving templated functions and classes and one of them can't compile (e.g. because the type `T` doesn't have the required member function), then error messages can get quite long and incomprehensible. A `static_assert` can prevent the compiler from even trying to instantiate a template for which you already know it will fail later down the line, and at the same time print a nicer error message.